# How can I create multiple instances of one sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am making a `CCSprite` (which is supposed to represent a bomb) on double taps, like this.

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)doubletapRecognizer
{
    [self placeBomb];
}

-(void)placeBomb
{
    NSLog(@"Bomb placed");
    _circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
    CGPoint circle0position = ccp(_cat.position.x , _cat.position.y);
    CGPoint c0TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle0position];
    CGPoint c0TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c0TileCoordt];//Supereffective way to get rid of decimals
    _circle.position = c0TileCoord;
    [self addChild:_circle];
    id fade = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:3.5 scale:0];
    [_circle runAction:fade];
    [self performSelector:@selector(explosion) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}
```

Then I run `-(void)explosion` which - surprise - makes it explode, which then again calls an checkForDamage method which tests for collisions within the explosion area in the lifespan of the explosion.

The problem is that I don't want to have a limit on amount of bombs (sprites), but when I place two bombs now, the explosion for the first one happens in the spot of the second one Which I obviously can't blame, because thats what I ask it to do. The explosion is based of the `_circle.position` The explosion block is about three hundred lines long, so I won't bother you with posting it here [(Heres pastebin link)](http://pastebin.com/uMAUvR4b), but as an example I will post the checkForDamage.

```
-(void)checkForDamage //Gets called with CCTime on explosion
{
    bool playerHit = NO;
    CGPoint bombPos = [self tileCoordForPosition:_circle.position];

    for (int i = 0; i <= explosionLenght; i++)
    {        
        CGPoint playerPosF = [self tileCoordForPosition:_cat.position];

        int bombX    = (bombPos.x + i);
        int bombY    = (bombPos.y + i);
        int bombNegX = (bombPos.x - i);
        int bombNegY = (bombPos.y - i);

        CGPoint centre = bombPos;
        CGPoint top    = ccp(centre.x, bombY);
        CGPoint left   = ccp(bombNegX, centre.y);
        CGPoint bottom = ccp(centre.x, bombNegY);
        CGPoint right  = ccp(bombX, centre.y);

        if (CGPointEqualToPoint(top, playerPosF) || 
            CGPointEqualToPoint(left, playerPosF) ||
            CGPointEqualToPoint(bottom, playerPosF) || 
            CGPointEqualToPoint(right, playerPosF))
        {
            playerHit = YES;

            NSLog(@"Player hit, BOOL:%i",playerHit);
            [self unschedule:@selector(checkForDamage)];
            break;
        }
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopCheckDamage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];    
}
```

How can I create multiple instances of the `_circle`bomb, in a such way that I can have multiple explosions and checks for damage going on at the same time. I tried doing it with a `for` loop and creating sprites with tags, but I don't know how to globally access and perform stuff on sprites by tag. I thought about making a different sprite for each explosion, like

```
if (explosion1exists) {explosion with circle1}, if (expl1 + expl2 exists) {expl with circle3}
```

But as I will have about up to 20-30 bombs placed at most, this is very uneffective and I thought that there must be a better way. Any methods to do this effectivly?

Comment: Can't you just add a `circle` parameter to both `explosion` and `checkForDamage`?

Comment: What you're looking for is object pooling: precreate the sprites, make them invisible, make the first invisible visible when needed and set its position etc. and when you're done with it, make it invisible again which also makes it available again for re-use. You also want to use sprite batching first and foremost since you're so concerned about efficiency.

Comment: @meaning-matters can you elaborate?

Comment: Having no experience with `CCSPrite` etc. I may miss the point.  I simply meant create a new `circle` then `[self performSelector:@selector(explosion) withObject:circle afterDelay:3];`.  Then inside `-  (void)explosion:(Circle*)circle` you do `[... checkForDamage:circle]`.

Comment: @meaning-matters I'm gonna try that.